# NexusDB Field with spaces ADO SQL

Tags: sql, ado, nexusdb

I can't figure out which syntax to use for fields in my NexusDB that have spaces in them.  I've tried the usual things like: [ ] `` but none of these work, the query just errors.  So an example query might be:

```
select `offical name` from MyTable
select [official name] from MyTable
```

*(these do not work*)

Thanks,

Karl..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter for delimited identifiers according to ISO 9075 (aka the SQL standard) is a double quote. Which is what NexusDB implementes:

```
select "official name" from MyTable
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't try that one.  Probably because I'm a SqlServer guy, and double quotes is something else.